# Tomcat 8.0 Cant connect to server (I will appreciate any helpful tips)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat8

I need your help with connecting to Tomcat server (I'm using Tomcat 8) using Eclipsce.
When I want to connect to server or run example servlet on server, I'm getting errors like these (What is more, I was able to connect with Tomcat Server 9 without any issues. I was looking for solution on stackoverflow, but unfortunatelly nothing has helped me):

> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FirstServlet]]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FirstServlet]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid  CarsFromAuction in servlet mapping
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3154)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3129)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1379)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1185)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:780)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>       ... 6 more
>
> lut 15, 2016 10:18:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
>   SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
>       at

Comment: Invalid CarsFromAuction in servlet mapping: an issue in the web.xml or annotations to define servlet names and mappings?

Comment: So I will try another way. I'm going to delete Tomcat Server from Eclipse and also project, then i set it anew and will see.

Comment: Okey, The problem has been solved. My solution worked. Thanks anyway.